# load upload file error on xls files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a file upload and a function to load that file in a GridView. when i choose a excel file and click upload button , the file upload to directory but give following error on load. For .txt files , it works fine
[image]

```
  Private Function UploadCSVFile() As String
    Try

        If fileCSV.HasFile Then
            strFileName = fileCSV.FileName
            hdnFileName.Value = fileCSV.FileName
            fileCSV.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strDirectory) & strFileName)
            Call LoadData(strFileName)        //  Gives error in this function
            lblImportMsg.Text = "File saved succesfully!"
        End If

        Return strFileName

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblImportMsg.Text = ex.ToString
        Return "None"
    End Try

End Function


Private Sub LoadData(ByVal strFileName As String)
    If Not strFileName = "" Then
        ds = New DataSet
        Dim strFilePath As String = Server.MapPath(strDirectory) '& strFileName
        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";Extended Properties=Text;")
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" & strFileName & "]", cnn)
        da.Fill(ds)
        gvFileInfo.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        gvFileInfo.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Open a CSV or XLS with Jet OLEDB and attain Table Lock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578324/how-to-open-a-csv-or-xls-with-jet-oledb-and-attain-table-lock)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Capitan. but Now it throws "System.UnauthorizedAccessException:Access to the path 'E:\Project\Simpla\StdUpload\rules.xlsx' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode" .   and it only occurs in case of .xls files

Comment: But this is another issue. Maybe it's readonly, or the user running the app has not permissions in that folder/file?
eh, wait! This is a xls or a XLSX? They're different formats!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A xls file can be interpreted as a text file, as a csv file (text with commas).
But XLSX it's different. If you would replace .xlsx with .zip, you would see (winzip, winrar. atc) that it's plenty of internal files ... it's an Office Open XML SpreadsheetML File Format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181(v=office.12).aspx

To open XLSX files try another connection String, like so:

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Path_to_your_file.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'")
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", cnn)
da.Fill(ds)
```